# How to set default column size(height,width) of columns of Data Grid View in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, datagrid, datagridview, datatable

I have a data table. After creating this table, I use data grid view to show data by simply using the code:

```
mydataGridView.DataSource = myTable;
```

By this, dataGridView creates columns and rows according to data from myTable automatically.
However, when I do that, I can't set the width of columns in dataGridView. What should i do to fix this?

I don't use any code for setting size. My dataGridView auto generates the columns and i want to set the size of these auto generated columns.

Comment: how did u try to set width of the column???can u post that code

Comment: You need to specify the columns you want to display explicitly and set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false.

Comment: @ChrisF but i don't want to disable auto generated columns. I just want to set their size, that's all.

Comment: Actually I was wrong - you should be able to set the size. There's the `AllowUserToResizeColumns` and `AllowUserToResizeRows` properties. Both of which are defaulted to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... into the xaml of your DataGrid, you have the ColumnWidth parameter that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a gotcha in this one:

```
MyGrid.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(2).width = SomeValue;
```

Pretty sure you always get at least one `TableStyle` and one `ColumnStyle` on instantiating the grid.
After that you have to create and add a column style for each column.
Same for `Rowstyle` if you need it as well.

If you style a grid from VS, set number of columns, only one columnstyle will be defined and it will be used for all columns from 0 onwards.
If you wantedf to make column 3 different then you have to set up columns 0,1 and 2. Then 3 and unless you want columns 4 .. n to be the same as three, a column 4 one to be used from then onwards.

Caught me out as well.

So you'll need code as far as I'm aware, you can make it generic though if you can pass in a list of style properties you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
dataGridView.Columns[i].Width = 60;
```

Comment: Please make sure you post a fully functional snippet. Now, it won't work since `i` is not declared.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.